# Execute bower command using bat file

Tags: json, node.js, batch-file, bower

I have a bower command like this

```
bower install GithubAccount/GithubRepo#versionNumber
```

I would like to do 2 things with this.

1. Execute from a batch file
2. Automate the `versionNumber` part by pulling the version number from my package.json file

Pulling the version number is pretty easy, using the node json plugin:

```
type package.json | json libDependencies.GithubRepo
```

but I can't figure out how to shoehorn this data into the .bat command I want to run.
Is there a way to do this or a better way to pull info for a bower command from an external source?

Comment: What output from `type ...`? Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28348875/edit) and paste it there. You could parse it using `for /F` command.

Comment: The output of type is my package.json file, which is a json string

Comment: Not sufficient info. Need to see all output to parse it with a script. Copy it from CLI window and paste as required above, please. At least the line containing version number to identify it

Comment: Ok, the type command outputs something like {"libDependencies": {"GithubRepo": "0.2.1"}}. The json command then does the parsing and returns "0.2.1"

Comment: The same output should be from (typed in CLI) command `for /F "delims=" %G in ('type package.json ^| json libDependencies.GithubRepo') do @echo %G` or, without surrounding quoes: `... do @echo %~G`

Comment: That's it, cheers. 
Put it in a post and I will accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script could look like

```
set "versionNumber=xxx"
for /F "delims=" %%G in (
  'type package.json ^| json libDependencies.GithubRepo'
) do set "versionNumber=%%~G"
if "%versionNumber%"=="xxx" (
    echo can't pull version Number
) else (
    echo bower install GithubAccount/GithubRepo#%versionNumber%
)
```

Get rid off the word `echo` from last command (`echo bower ...`) if output looks well.